# Find multiple substrings in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check if there are two or more values ​​in a string, regardless of their positions within said string. For example, if I want a condition of **"OR"** in regex, I would do so:

```
/(a|b)/.test("a") // true
```

But what I need is an **"AND"**; something like this:

```
/(a&b)/.test("a") // false
/(a&b)/.test("b") // false
/(a&b)/.test("a b") // true
/(b&a)/.test("a b") // true
/(a&b&c)/.test("a b") // false
/(a&b&c)/.test("a c b") // true
```

Obviously this syntax is not correct...

These values `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. are pulled from an array. I've tried using a combination of `eval()` and `indexOf(a)  !== -1 && indexOf(b) !== -1` but that was too slow, which is why I'm turning to regexes.

Comment: discussion moved to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17952/discussion-between-guilherme-nascimento-and-nulluserexception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're matching fixed strings, you could just use:

```
function matchAll(str, arr)
{
  for (var i=0; i<arr.length; ++i) {
    if (str.indexOf(arr[i]) === -1) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

matchAll('a', ['a']); // true
matchAll('a', ['a', 'b']); // false
matchAll('a b', ['a', 'b']); // true
matchAll('a b c', ['a', 'b']); // true
matchAll('a b', ['a', 'b', 'c']); // false
matchAll('a c b', ['a', 'b', 'c']); // true
matchAll('c a b', ['a', 'b', 'c']); // true
```

If you're looking for fixed strings, `.indexOf()` will be faster than regexes.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
/(?=.*a)(?=.*b)/.test("a")
```

Comment: To those wondering what this is: [Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (zero-width assertions)

Comment: You do not like the sign "?" . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The answer @OmarJackman posted will do what you're asking for. However, it's worth noting that his solution uses lookarounds which require more processing than simpler regexes. If you're looking for good performance I'd recommend that you just run two separate regexes (test for case `a` and then for case `b`). Two simple regexes will run orders of magnitude faster than one complex one, especially as the search text becomes larger.

**Edit:** As noted in the comments, "orders of magnitude" is an unfair exaggeration of the performance impact, but performance should be considered regardless.

Comment: I'm not convinced lookaround would make a regex "orders of magnitude" slower.

Comment: Yes worry too much about the performance, if you have any examples without "?" 'd be grateful. Thanks

Comment: @NullUserException You're probably right, "orders of magnitude" is almost certainly an exaggeration, but regardless the performance point is worth noting (especially when a simpler solution like CaffGeek's is just as readable while being more performant)

Comment: Benchmarks: http://jsperf.com/regex-lookahead ; here it is with shorter input: http://jsperf.com/regex-lookahead/2 CC: @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: @NullUserException Wow, that is really interesting. At least in my browser (Chrome, webkit) lookahead's performance for 2000 char strings is negligible, only **7%** slower. But for the short 100 char strings, lookahead's performance is **72%** slower! That's just weird. Opposite from what I would have assumed.

Comment: Only the "tworgx" comes close to what I need, but the regex is generated automatically with multiple values ​​to check, so I wanted to be alone in a RegEx. Any other ideas? Thanks.